# Keras - How to using Cnn trained model on video image.?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, data-science-model, object-detection

I have trained Cat and dog image using CNN with Python ( total 10K, 8K for training and 2K for testing ). 
I want to make prediction in a video. Video Contain both cat and dog at a single moment. How can I do that. ?
How to make bounding rect with text on cat and dog image in video.
Thanks for helping.